# Webpack taking ages to launch before beginning build

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm running webpack to build a very simple hello world script. It's compiling in 577ms according to the output, which would be fine, except it actually takes about 5 minutes.

I'm running it from an npm script. Here's my package JSON.

```
{
  "name": "es6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

It displays `webpack --mode development` but then hangs for five minutes or so before doing anything else. What's up with that?

I don't have webpack installed globally by accident, I've checked that. I do have sass installed globally via NPM, could that be causing issues?

The final output is this:

```
λ npm run start

> es6@1.0.0 start u:\DnA\Analytics\Oli\es6
> webpack --mode development

Hash: cd6869ce2bd9b1e1c971
Version: webpack 4.29.5
Time: 557ms
Built at: 02/27/2019 4:14:28 PM
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  3.82 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[./src/index.js] 43 bytes {main} [built]
```

Comment: That drive letter `u:` makes me wonder if there's some sort of network drive involved here.

Comment: There is, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: If that's a network drive, that's mostly likely the issue. Webpack is building quickly and reporting back correctly, but the initial startup is what's taking so long. That startup requires contact with the network drive which is probably the bottleneck here.

Comment: Thanks - I'll move it to my local drive and try again.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Also brought compilation time down to .43ms. If someone wants to submit it as an answer, I'll happilly accept it.

Comment: Webpack is an node application, and needs to read a large amount of files during it's startup. On a SSD or a hard disk, this is fine, but it really gives issues on a network share, as it only loads the next file from node_modules when the previous one is done loading. (Adding this here for @spender, so he could add it in his answer, since he was the first one with the idea of a network drive causing issues)

Comment: well technically it depends how you are mounting your drive, try to use samba ... and set the UseDns to false from your sshd config, check if there is IO usage on the disk / check CPU try to understand the bottleneck. I use samba share and I have no problem with webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the large number of small files involved in most node libraries/applications, they are not well suited to running from network drives. Move to a local drive to see things improve.